# Compare string values of two columns in pandas and find vector cosine

Tags: python, string, pandas, vector, comparison

Hi I found some code here that can turn two strings into vectors, and then compare them to return a cosine value of their similarity

```
import re, math
from collections import Counter
import sys
import pandas as pd

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
     intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
     numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

     sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
     sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
     denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

     if not denominator:
        return 0.0
     else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

text1 = 'string one'
text2 = 'string two'

vector1 = text_to_vector(text1)
vector2 = text_to_vector(text2)

print get_cosine(vector1 , vector2)
```

I am trying to apply this to a pandas dataframe so that instead of using two random strings, it iterates over each row and turns the string value of each row into a vector, and then returns a new column with the result.  The above example returns 0.5 because string and string match, but two and one dont, meaning 1/2 = 0.5 words match.  I have two columns `df['Address 1']` and `df['Address 2']` that have string address values in each I would like to compare and get the cosine value of their similarity and return this value as a new column `df['Address Cosine']`

For example, if `df['Address 1']` holds `'685 EASY STREET', '122 FOURTH AVE', '9189 FIFTY NINTH ST'` and df['Address 2'] holds `'685 EASY STREET', '240 FOURTH AVE', '9189 THIRTY EIGHTH ST'`
then I would expect `df['Address Cosine']` to contain `'1.0', '0.66', '0.5'`

Any ideas?